# CSS not working on device

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova

I am not understanding why this CSS is not working on my device (Android 4.4 and iOS 8.0):

```
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, $gcolor1, $gcolor2, $gcolor3, $gcolor4); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, $gcolor1, $gcolor2, $gcolor3, $gcolor4); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, $gcolor1, $gcolor2, $gcolor3, $gcolor4); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, $gcolor1, $gcolor2, $gcolor3, $gcolor4); /* Standard syntax */
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

body .view-container.tab-content {
  background-color: transparent;
}

body .pane, .menu, .view, .list, .item       {
    background: transparent;
}
```

The background just turns white, despite that it does work in the browser (on Phone and on Chrome). What is going on?

FYI, I deploy the app using Phonegap Build and I apply this CSS on an Ionic/Angular project.

Comment: how are you calling ur css can you show me

Comment: @Sport: as you indicated in your answer, below the ionic.min.css

Answer (score 1):

It may be missing this:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,$gcolor1), color-stop(33%,$gcolor2), color-stop(66%,$gcolor3), color-stop(100%,$gcolor4));
```

That should be specific to Safari 4+ and Chromes

Comment: Can you provide the compiled css so that we can see what's the actual stylesheet? Also to be sure, try to change the background to red for example to see if it reacts whatsoever.

Comment: yes I tried to change the background to red as follows: background: red !important; and that worked. How can I share the compiled stylesheet (very large file)?

Comment: Paste only the part where you style body. The compilation may have broken the syntax somehow. It has to be somewhere in the gradient css, otherwise it wouldn't make any sense...

Answer (score 1):

try this

in Index.html add this

```
  <link href="css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
```

then copy your css file inside CSS folder

add this  in index.html

```
    <script>
 if (navigator.userAgent === undefined) {
                    navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function() {
                                               return("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit");
                    });
                }

</script>
```

Comment: Nope, I already had this line of code. It must be something gradient related.

Comment: Did not work unfortunately as well. I am considering just to take an image instead.